# Can't update/create Azure table in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio

I'm hoping this is me being stupid, but I don't seem to be able to click the Update button in VS2022 when creating or modifying a DB table.  I was able to copy and paste the SQL in the bottom part into a query window and actually create the table.  I can also run select queries and even write queries via code, but I can't get this Update button to un-grey:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: While we try to create it manually as shown in the above qsn, it will show the `CREATE TABLE` command at down of [Visual Studio](https://i.imgur.com/HSqMI25.png) and the script will be selected automatically so by clicking on `Start` at top of the Visual Studio the table will be created successfully.

Comment: Thanks, but I am able to execute the SQL manually, I'd just rather be able to alter the table without having to write the SQL every time.  I'm not sure why the Update button is greyed out.

Comment: I tried in `SQL Server Database Project` in Visual Studio 2022 and the `update` button is [enable](https://i.imgur.com/lPrMcDJ.png) in my case, once you try to update VS 2022 if it is having any pending updates and check whether it is enabled or not.

Comment: Thanks @Balaji but I'm fully updated.

Comment: Still it is not enabled? even after updating VS

Comment: Can you check the SQL Server Version using `SELECT @@version` and share the output.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Feb  2 2024 04:20:23   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

This is a SQL DB hosted on Azure

Answer (score 0):

> Can't update/create Azure table in Visual Studio 2022

The create or update in Azure SQL table through Visual Studio 2022 fails because of the SQL Server version used in Azure portal and the version used in Visual Studio are different. By observing this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-visual-studio-and-sql-azure-databases/), the `Update` button will be enable only if the sql server version is same in both Visual Studio and Azure portal.

As the version is different in both Azure SQL and Visual Studio. So, the `update` button is disable as you can see below:

**SQL Server version in Visual Studio 2022:**
[image]

**SQL Server version in Azure SQL Server:**
[image]

If the version in Visual Studio and Azure SQL Server matches, `update` button is successfully enabled as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Balaji, I confirmed when I open my local ones at version 13/15, I can update those.  Searching around on the internet, it seems that Azure is stuck at V12 (or uses a different numbering system and 12 is the latest), so how would I go about changing one of the versions to make it compatible with the other?  I did try changing the compatibility level on the database to 120 and 130, but that didn't make a difference.